# Php and Mysql communication

Tags: php, mysql

i've Apach2, Mysql and php (also php-mysql); i'm trying to insert from a form (varchar, varchar, password, date, varchar)into the table utenti in my db music:
[Describe Utenti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE5jw.png)

I'm using procedural style mysqli: It says me "Insert success" but it doesn't write for real on the Db;

```
    <?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$datanascita = $_POST['datanascita'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "popolo";
$dbname = "music";

//Connessione

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

//verifica eventuali errori
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connesione fallita" . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} else {

    echo "Connected \n";
    //Inserting record in table using INSERT query

    $mysqli = "INSERT INTO Utenti (`nome`, `cognome`, `password`, `datanascita`, `email`) 
    VALUES ($nome, $cognome, $password, $datanascita, $email)";

    mysqli_query($conn, $mysqli);

    echo "Insert success";

}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: [`or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) would have helped you *mi amico*.

Answer (score -1):

whatever your query succeeded or not this message `echo "Insert success";` will output, you should check if your query succeeded  first , you must your varchar in 2 `'`

```
$mysqli = "INSERT INTO Utenti (`nome`, `cognome`, `password`, `datanascita`, `email`) 
VALUES ('$nome', '$cognome','$password', '$datanascita', '$email')";
```

you can check like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysqli);
if($result){
echo "Insert success";
} else {
echo "Insert failed, Error: ".$mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: `echo "Insert failed";` won't help them during development. [*This will...*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) ;-) as stated up there.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I follow your suggest and it works!